# How to check the given name persent in database column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to check the given name present in the no of columns. I have post my table record structure below. I want to filter the approved list details for the given name.

```
  Name      forward1   forward2    forward3   forward4  forward5  status
  Ajay      vino       arun         jose                          Approved
  Hersone   arun       jose                                       Pending
  Stefi     vino       jose         arun                          Approved
  Alex      arun       Hersone      vino                          Approved
```

I need the Jose record  with approved status like this:

```
  Name      forward1   forward2    forward3   forward4  forward5  status
  Ajay      vino       arun         jose                          Approved
  Stefi     vino       jose         arun                          Approved
```

Am new for this field. Please help me to do this . sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE status= 'Approved' AND
      (forward1 ='jose' OR  forward2 ='jose' OR  forward3 ='jose' 
        OR  forward4 ='jose'  OR  forward5 ='jose');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE status= 'Approved' AND
      (forward1 LIKE '%jose%' OR  
       forward2 LIKE '%jose%' OR  
       forward3 LIKE '%jose%' OR  
       forward4 LIKE '%jose%' OR  
       forward5 LIKE '%jose%');
```

EDIT: `WHERE condition` depends on your requirements
for exact match you can use `forward1 = 'jose'`

Comment: I don't think he wants text match.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = select * from table_name where forward3 = 'jose' and status = 'approved'
```

Comment: what is with "jose" in forward2?

Comment: query = select * from table_name where forward2 = 'jose' or forword3 = 'jose' and status = 'approved'